# Google MLKit Barcode Scanning can't read less than 5 digits in Codabar

Tags: android, ios, google-mlkit

I use Google MLKit/barcode-scanning(16.0.3) to read barcodes on standard iOS and Android cameras.
I want to support various barcodes, but there is a big problem only in reading with Codabar in it.

The 4-digit and 5-digit codes are barely recognized only by the barcode displayed on the PC monitor, and are not recognized at all by the printed barcode.
(Example) A1234A, A12345B

Also, if the code is 3 digits or less, it will not be recognized by the PC monitor at all.
(Example) A123A, A12B

I wondered if there was a problem with the barcode resolution, so I tried changing the thickness of the lines and spaces to 2 to 3 times, and changing the character spacing, but the results did not change.

I want to be able to read Codabar with more than 2 digits.
There is no problem with 6 digits or more, so I feel that MLKit limits it so that it will not be misread.
Is there a way to change the digit limit setting?

Or should I consider the ZXing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, there's a limit (min length is 6) internally to reduce false positive. It's being considered to allow configuring it externally, so please stay tuned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Expect and wait.

Comment: From Google
Linear formats: **Codabar**, Code 39, Code 93, Code 128, EAN-8, EAN-13, ITF, UPC-A, UPC-E
2D formats: Aztec, Data Matrix, PDF417, QR Code

[Link][1]

Details:
Note that this API does not recognize barcodes in these forms:
 1. 1D Barcodes with only one character


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning
I don't see a limit of 6 characters for Codaba. Why do you know?